# NSXMLParser parserDidStartDocument freezes app

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, refresh, freeze

I tried to add some operations after call

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
//NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Caricamento..."
                                       message:@"\n"
                                      delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
[alertView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView show];
```

}

But it freeze the app for a while, and then, when finished the XML parse, loads the AlertView, ecc. Same thing with the UIRefreshControl. I slide down the tableView, and the app freeze while parsing, I cant see the spinner rotating.

Any idea?

Edit:
here I call the first time the parser:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSString * path = @"thexmlpath.xml";
if(!caricato)
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXMLFileAtURL:) toTarget:self withObject:path];
    //[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];

caricato = YES;}
```

Here I call when I use the RefreshControl:

```
- (void)refreshControlRequest{


NSLog(@"refreshing...");

NSString * path = @"thexmlpath.xml";
[self performSelector:@selector(parseXMLFileAtURL:) withObject:path];}
```

Comment: I think I have to add the XML parsing task in background, so it doesnt freeze the app, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Show more code of where you are calling parse. That is where you need to put it in background queue and then call updating the user interface controls on the main queue.

Comment: Now I add the performSelector, but the app crash due to: EXC_BAD_ACCESS thread error.

Comment: Based on what you suggested about your level of expertise, using NSThread detachNewThread is a bad idea. Not sure what you are doing at parseXMLFileAtURL: method. Can you show that code

Comment: Thank you, now I get it: I was wrong using detachNewThreadSelector, I used performSelectorInBackground for the parser, and performSelectorOnMainThread for the AlertView, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
//NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Caricamento..."
                                           message:@"\n"
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
    [alertView addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [alertView show];
});
dispatch_release(queue);


}
```

Comment: iYaniv your solution is correct, but in addition to what is being done suggested by you, the parsing has to be moved into a background queue and then use the code suggested by you. Because right now, the parsing itself is on the main thread and if you dispatch some thing to the main queue, it will happen after the work on the main thread is completed.